# AngularJS - unit testing a controller method that gets called on initialization

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angularjs-controller

In my AngularJS Controller, I have a `$scope.init` method that gets called when the controller gets initialized.  `$scope.init` calls `$scope.loadData` and `$scope.loadNames`, which each fire an HTTP GET Request to an API to fetch some data.

I have written some unit tests using `$httpBackend` to mock the API responses and test `$scope.loadData` and `$scope.loadNames`.  Those work fine but something that I can't seem to test is the `$scope.init` method.  Is there a way to mock or stub a method that gets called on controller initialization?  What are the best practices for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that the scope objects changed in `$scope.init` have the proper values after the controller initialization. You can even try to change the values of those objects, and rerun the init method, and check that everything matches afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can test:

- the state of the controller is as expected after it is "initialized"
- verify that loadnames and loaddata gets called (jasmine's spyOn+toHaveBeenCalled)
- play with a promise object mocking the loadnames/loaddata methods response to verify your behavior under unexpected conditions